# Python - Saving Entire Class Object Except For A Large Attribute

Tags: python, python-2.7, serialization, python-3.x, save

I have an object which I want to save but one of it's attributes is very large and doesn't need to be saved. How can I save the object except that one attribute. Below is my current solution.

```
class Example(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.attribute_one = 1
        self.attribute_two = 'blah blah'
        ...
        self.attribute_large = very_large_object

save_this_except_attribute_large = Example()
```

One possible solution would be

```
def save_example(example):
    save_this = copy.deepcopy(example)
    save_this.attribute_large = None
    pickle.dump(save_this,open('save_path','w'))
```

Except the above solution isn't memory efficient, as we will have 2 attribute_large in memory before we set one of them to None.

Any suggestions

Comment: Are you using a module called `deep`? The one on PyPI does not appear to have a `copy()`. Or are you using `copy.deepcopy()`?

Comment: oops, that was a typo, meant copy.deepcopy()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a dict comprehension along with [`__getstate__` / `__setstate__`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#object.__getstate__) to build a new dict to be pickled, leaving out the large attribute:

```
class Example(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.attribute_one = 1
        self.attribute_two = 'blah blah'
        ...
        self.attribute_large = very_large_object

    def __getstate__(self):
        d = self.__dict__
        self_dict = {k : d[k] for k in d if k != 'attribute_large'}
        return self_dict

    def __setstate__(self, state):
        self.__dict__ = state
```

Using `__getstate__`/`__setstate__` allows the code that actually does the pickling to not have to worry about the implementation details of `Example`; it just pickles the object, and the object itself does the right thing.